# UITableview cells are hidden under section after animating.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

so I have a tableview that contains 3 different sections, and once you click on one of the sections a group of cells drop down from the section. Now I'm trying to have the table view scroll to the last cell in each one of the section. I've come up with this so far:

```
[atableView beginUpdates];

    [atableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathToInsert withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
    [atableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [atableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];

    [atableView endUpdates];

   self.openSectionIndex = section;
```

So when I use this method it moves the entire view up just like I want however some of the top cells are cut off and hidden under the section that they dropped down from. I might be calling this method too early, and it's calling before the rows have finished animating, or are they bouncing back up under the section. I am able to pull down on the tableview, and the cells then come out from underneath the section. Any ideas?

Comment: the default behavior of cells is to lay underneath the section.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a collapsable section component like what you're describing and may have a solution for you.

My implementation is in the [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) library. Try running the "Collapse" sample project. Expand the first section. Then expand the section section. You will see that while the cells are animating, the table scrolls to display as much of the section on screen as possible.

The trick to doing this is to realize that you need to scroll to a position that doesn't necessarily exist yet because the table view doesn't recalculate it's content size until some time later in the process. The solution I used is to explicitly set the table view's `contentSize` to a value that contains the position you want to scroll to. My implementation in looks like this:

```
/*
 Force table to scroll to the specified location even if it is beyond the current
 content area. Use this to scroll to a future location during animiated table updates
 with the assumption that the location will be valid after the updates.
 */
- (void)forceTableScrollBasedOnExpectedSize:(CGFloat)scrollLocation animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGSize expectedMinimumContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
    if (expectedMinimumContentSize.height < scrollLocation) {
        // Temporarily expand the content area to contain the scroll location.
        // The table will overwrite this during the update process.
        expectedMinimumContentSize.height = scrollLocation;
        self.tableView.contentSize = expectedMinimumContentSize;
    }
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, scrollLocation-1, 1, 1) animated:animated];
}
```

where `scrollLocation` is the bottom most position you want to make visible. You can see more details how this is used in [`UITableViewController+ScrollOptimizer.m`](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/TLIndexPathTools/Extensions/UITableViewController+ScrollOptimizer.m).

I'm not exactly sure this applies to your problem. If it doesn't, please elaborate more in your question.

Comment: Yeah, that totally makes sense that I wouldn't be able to set a specific scroll position because I attempted to use [atableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom animated:YES]; and it kept producing an error. I'm thinking that this may lead me in the right direction, but the code I have now works for what I need except that one minor little detail.

Comment: I think I should have elaborated more, but basically the problem began with my table view rows dropping beyond the view or screen. So I figured that offsetting the view once the main section header what selected would fix the problem, which it did, partially. So that's where the real problem lies.